# Visual Studio 2010 X86 Release ignoring #pragma warnings and /W0 C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, compiler-warnings

Visual Studio 2010 Win32 X86 Release ignoring #pragma warnings and /W0 C++

All other combos (debug and X64) supress using #pragma fine, but not in release X86.  Also ignoring command line switch /WO for suppress all warnings.

Any clues on this one?

```
#pragma warning(disable:6308)

Warning 2 warning C6308: 'realloc' might return null pointer: ...

... /Zi /nologo /W0 /WX /O2 /Oi /Oy- /D "WIN32" ...
```

Comment: I would recommend resolving warnings rather than ignoring them ...

Comment: you should post the code generating this warning

Comment: IIRC there are some warnings that you cannot disable in MSVC, however hard you try (ditto for the linker; some people went as far as reverse engineering the executable to have them disabled). Anyway, you really should try to fix the code in the first place.

Comment: This warning is code analysis related. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyhb0b82(v=vs.100)

Comment: The prev comment is correct.  Turns out this was an analysis issue on just WIN32 release.  As far as the other non-answers, there are reasons I asked the question.  I am NOT looking for a code fix in this case.  Just wondering why WIN32 has different results than WIN64.  Fix for now is to disable code analysis for WIN32 Release with is ok in this case.

Comment: still you'd better answer my non-answer and post code reproducing the problem :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need / want a code fix, disabling Code Analysis for WIN32 release will fix this issue.